# CSS to make divs auto float

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

I have a `main div` under which there can be `one or two sub divs`. When there are two sub-divs, I would want them to be displayed side-by-side. But If I have only one sub div, then I'd want it to be displayed in the center. Can this be achieved by using CSS or should I take help of JavaScript? Using the following CSS I'm able to achieve the side-by-side part of it. But I'm not sure how to go forward when there is only one sub div

HTML:

```
<div id="maindiv">
    <div class="subdiv">
        <p>Div One</p>
    </div>

    <div class="subdiv">
        <p>Div Two</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.subdiv {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
}

div#maindiv {
    border: 2px solid black; 
    height: 120px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: There is no one good way to do this; it depends on what you want the page to look like.  You could give them `display: inline-block` instead of `float`, and then give the container `text-align: center;` for example.

Comment: Thank You. That worked. Hope you give an answer instead of a comment, so that I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`. Try to remove the second sub div in my example fiddle and you can see the desired result.

```
div.subdiv {
display:inline-block;
padding: 20px;
}

div#maindiv {
border: 2px solid black; 
height: 120px;
width: 200px;
text-align:center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mo7qyenv/1/)